# Android studio SQL - How to return data in a string array

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQL method here. I would like to return the data in a String[] array.

How do I do that exactly?

Thank you!

```
public String[] getLikedSongs() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] LikeSong;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + COL_4 + " FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " IS NOT NULL", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String note = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return LikeSong;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the array's length and this can be done only after the Cursor fetches all the rows. Then set its length to the nimber of rows of the Cursor.
Then inside the while loop set the items of the array:

```
public String[] getLikedSongs() {
    String[] LikeSong = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_4 + " FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " IS NOT NULL", null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        LikeSong = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            LikeSong[i] = cursor.getString(0);
            i++;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return LikeSong;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it! I highly appreciate your help :)